# Toggle highlight in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I need to implement a functionality, where I have certain categories on my website, and need to always highlight the category clicked by the user.
It is also a requirement that there can always be only one highlighted item at a time.
Now, I can do this with the code below, but I also want to make it work so when I click on the highlighted item, it removes the highlight from it. I know why this code doesn't work like that: First, it always removes every highlight, so when I click (this function is attached to an event listener) there is never an occasion when my 'active-li' class is active on the class.
But no matter how much I think about it, I just can't get my mind around this problem. How do I change this code to work in a way that it removes the highlight from a highlighted element, but also makes sure that only one item can be highlighted at the same time?

```
function highlightClas(activeClass) {
for (let category of categories.children) {
    category.classList.remove('active-li');
}
if (activeClass.classList.contains('active-li')) {
    activeClass.classList.remove('active-li');
} else {
    activeClass.classList.add('active-li');
}
```

}

The relevant HTML:

```
                <div class="filters">
                    <h3>CATEGORIES</h3>
                    <ul>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.active-li {
background-color: aqua;
```

}

And the relevant JS:

```
var categories = document.querySelector('.filters ul');
async function populateCategories() {
    const categoriesUrl = '/api/products/categories';
    const response = await fetch(categoriesUrl);
    const categoriesResp = await response.json();

    for (let category of categoriesResp) {
        let template = `<a>${category}</a>`;
        let appendedCategory = document.createElement('li');
        appendedCategory.innerHTML = template;
        categories.append(appendedCategory);
        appendedCategory.addEventListener('click', () => {
            highlightClas(appendedCategory);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to show a complete example.  Where is the html and css if any?  where is categories defined?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: not very well!  create a working snippet